# After completing MergeSort method, it returns only 1 number

Tags: java, mergesort

After completing `MergeSort` method, it returns only a few numbers. In a last recursion, the right array has no numberss. There are some "debug" sout', don't give attention. Tried to do something with middle var.

Example output, with 50 elements array:

Original array:

```
914 75 5 811 775 500 611 991 524 306 208 673 427 938 214 789 493 390 
705 140 131 550 346 851 635 957 828 350 612 442 657 795 211 309 119 
368 473 884 364 851 195 276 891 247 462 123 111 975 384 970
```

Output:

```
914 427 75
```

Here is the code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> MergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> str) {
    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();
    if (str.size() <= 1) {
        return str;
    }

    int middle = str.size() / 2;
    System.out.println("Mid: "+ middle);

    for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
        left.add(str.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = middle; i < str.size() - middle; i++) {
        right.add(str.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Left start!");
    left = MergeSort(left);
    print(left);
    System.out.println("Left stop!");
    System.out.println("Right start!");
    right = MergeSort(right);
    print(right);
    System.out.println("Right stop!");

    return Merge(left, right);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> Merge(ArrayList<Integer> left, ArrayList<Integer> right) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (right.size() > 0 && left.size() > 0) {
        if (right.get(0) <= left.get(0)) {
            result.add(left.get(0));
            left.remove(0);
        } else {
            result.add(right.get(0));
            right.remove(0);
        }
    }

    while (left.size() > 0) {
        result.add(left.get(0));
        left.remove(0);
    }
    while (right.size() > 0) {
        result.add(right.get(0));
        right.remove(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I guess the condition in this loop `for (int i = middle;i<str.size()-middle;i++)` is wrong. I should be `i < str.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int i = middle;i<str.size()-middle;i++) {
>     right.add(str.get(i));
> }
> ```

Should be

```
for (int i = middle;i<str.size();i++) {
    right.add(str.get(i));
}
```

In fact, `List`s have [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), so `left` and `right` could be created as

```
List<Integer> left=str.subList(0,middle);
List<Integer> right=str.subList(middle,str.size());
```

(Though it would slightly defeat the purpose of practising - which is the goal I assume, as `List`s also have their own [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) after all)